# Changing Nativescript Listview `onItemTap` background color?

Tags: android, css, angular, listview, nativescript

I have a `ListView`  :

[image]

This is the markup :

```
<ListView   [items]="items " class="list-group" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)"  >
    <ng-template  let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even"  >
        <Label [text]='item._name' class="row list-group-item" [id]="'lbl' + i"></Label>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

However - when I click an item - nothing happens with the `background-color`. ( *i'm expecting to have some indication of being tapped*).

I've already have this code (which does execute when I tap )

```
  onItemTap($event)
    {
        var lbl = <Label>$event.view.getViewById("lbl" + $event.index);
        console.log(lbl.text);
    }
```

**BTW**

If it was a `button` instead of `label` - I could've done :

```
.row:highlighted{
    background-color:#00A3FF;
}
```

But as you can see - I'm using `Label`.

**Question**
How can I highlight the label's background color when tapped ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want you could do something with the touch event

```
<Label #label (touch)="highlight(label,$event)" text="My Label"></Label>
```

then in your components class

```
highlight(label:Label, $event:TouchGestureEventData){
       if ($event.action === TouchAction.down) {
            label.backgroundColor = // on touch background color
        }
        if ($event.action === TouchAction.cancel || $event.action === TouchAction.up) {
            label.backgroundColor = // on back to original color
        }
}
```

Comment: oops copy and paste fail, that was code from a directive I used elsewhere. I've deleted it just disregard.

Comment: It does work - but now - the main event isn't invoked : (itemTap of ListView) :https://i.stack.imgur.com/5irez.png

Comment: hmm. could you include the event in the highlight function? there may be a collision there because of the main list view and hightlight

Comment: To tell you the truth - I prefer to add eventListener to the listview via `itemTap` rather than attaching `(touch)` to each element in the listview....What i'm trying to say that I wanted to use the functionality that you supplied in the `itemTap` event (which is **one** event attached to the ListView). **BUT** `$event` on `itemTap` doesn't include `$event.action` as in `touch` event......hO can I solve this ?

Comment: Alternatively instead of including it the touch event you could move the tap event to the label `(tap)="onItemTap($event)"` not sure you may need to change which i believe should have the action in it's event at well.